# Q: Intellisense when using context.prisma

Tags: graphql, intellisense, javascript-intellisense, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm creating my graphql layer with prisma. I have a question about using prisma with typescript in the resolvers.

In the documentation it is suggested to import prisma to get intellisense:

```
import { prisma } from '../generated/prisma-client'
```

If you do so, when you are writing a resolver like this one, you won't get any suggestions.

```
const user = (parent, args, context, info) => context.prisma.bodyweight({id: parent.id}).user()
```

To get the suggestions you would have to write it without referencing the context adding the reference later, which predisposes you to forget it and create bugs.

Is there a way to fix it (maybe in the tsconfig)?

Comment: Hey @DanielMateosLabrador, can you please accept the answer if it solved your issue? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get intellisense by typing the context:

```
import { Prisma } from '../generated/prisma-client';
export interface Context{
  prisma: Prisma;
}

const user = (parent, args, context: Context, info) => context.prisma.bodyweight({id: parent.id}).user()
```

You should also checkout graphqlgen. That will allow you to automatically type the resolvers. https://github.com/prisma/graphqlgen#graphqlgen